# webmethod isn't catching ajax POST

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, post, webmethod

I'm trying to call a server side method with ajax. This is what I've got:

**Client side:**

```
function accept(thisButton) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/editMaxUsers",
        data: '{param: "' + $(thisButton).prev().val() + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json: charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) { alert("successful" + result.d); }
    });
}
```

**Server side:**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string editMaxUsers(string maxUsers)
{
    return maxUsers;   //I also have a breakpoint here that isn't stopping the execute
}
```

When I check the calls with firebug I can see that the POST is being sent and looks fine. But Nothing seems to be happening on server side. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Don't know if it's relevant, but the url already contains some parameters. I've tried the following `url: "Default.aspx/" + window.location.search + "editMaxUsers"` but no success.

Comment: Are you getting successful response? If yes, then you may not be using right code to debug. Usually this happens when you open a different branch in source control in VS and running some other branch in IIS

Comment: @VidhyardhiGorrepati No, I'm not getting any response (as far as I can tell)

Comment: what status code are you getting when you are calling server side method?can you add a error callback in jquery ajax method

Comment: @F11 status code is 200 OK. I added a error callback and it fired. Not sure how I can get any more info, I just added an `alert('failed');`

Comment: @F11 The first link you posted was the one I followed. Anything specific that I missed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96469/discussion-between-f11-and-johan-hjalmarsson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Go to App_Start/RouteConfig and change

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

to

```
 settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
```

2.As @F11 said the paramter in the WebMethod and the key in the json object should be with the same name and what I strongly recommend is not to build json object manually. It is better to do:

```
function accept(thisButton) {
 var data = {};
 data.maxUsers = $(thisButton).prev().val(); 
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/editMaxUsers",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json: charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) { alert("successful" + result.d); }
});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The parameters of your WebMethod need to match the parameter name you are passing in.
Change

```
data: '{param: "' + $(thisButton).prev().val() + '" }',
```

to

```
data: '{maxUsers: "' + $(thisButton).prev().val() + '" }',
```

Comment: Still didn't solve anything. Exact same behavior as before =/ I've started on a workaround though so I might be able to skip the whole ajax-thing ^^